# SQL-SERVER-2008: How do I map user variables to multiple fields in a query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I really just need to know if this is possible without writing two queries to fill the variables.
I want to map the index of the fields in the query to the user variables.
Here is what I need to do :

```
DECLARE @a varchar(20);
DECLARE @b varchar(20);

SET @a(0)@b(1) = (
SELECT TOP 1
       a
      ,b
FROM
       c)

If @a = 'val1' and @b = 'xval2' Then

Begin
     Select 'test'
End
```

Obviously above won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the @ variables within the query:

`SELECT @a=a, @b=b FROM c...`

Here is another example:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(100)
DECLARE @b varchar(100)

SELECT @a=Login, @b=FunctionalGroupID FROM Login
WHERE LoginID=100

SELECT @a
SELECT @b
```

This prints a login and a department group from a table called login and assigns them to the variables a and b respectively.

In your case:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(20);
DECLARE @b varchar(20);

SELECT TOP 1 @a=a, @b=b FROM c

IF @a = 'val1' AND @b = 'xval2' THEN
  BEGIN
     SELECT 'test'
  END
```